# How to iterate a string literal based on date using while loop in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table that i query to give me a list of processes. The naming convention of these processes changes based on the current month and year we are in. So for the month of July, it will give me the "07" with the year "18" in the name and so on.
**This is a test query**

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(process_ID , 6, 2) as Procnumber,[process_ID]
FROM [Hana].[dbo].[processActivityEvent] v
WHERE process_ID like 'AB18-07_shield%'
```

I have used a substring to get the month out which give me:

**Result**

```
+------------+----------------------+
| Procnumber |      Process_ID      |
+------------+----------------------+
|         07 | AB18-07_shield123456 |
+------------+----------------------+
```

I will like to iterate this number(month) whenever we move into a new month which will be August. I want a while loop or any function that will either add 1 to the next number or replace the current number so i wont have to hard code it into my query or modify my query whenever we move into a new month or year. I want to automate this process. 
Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the Year calculation added it would be

> WHERE process_ID like 'AB' + RIGHT(RTRIM(YEAR(GETDATE())), 2)
>   +'-'+RIGHT('0' + RTRIM(MONTH(GETDATE())), 2)+'_shield%'

Comment: Thank you so much your prompt reply user1516044. I will try it.

Comment: Thank you once again. The real test will be next month which is in 4 days.

Comment: Hello user1516044, the formula works great but the issue is that, the database hasnt populated yet for my getdate to work, what if i add a if else statement? will that be possible? How do I structure my if statement to still continue to pick the previous month and once the current month shows  up then it should select that? i dont know if you would see my new comment or not but if you dont reply, I will create a new question. Thank you all.

Comment: Are you running this in a stored proc?  I probably would, if you aren't and you can.  i would execute your desired where clause and get a count.  Assign it to a variable.  If @Count > 0 then select your results.  Else select previous month results.   `code` declare @count int; select @count = count(process_ID) from ... where process_ID like 'AB' + RIGHT(RTRIM(YEAR(GETDATE())), 2) +'-'+RIGHT('0' + RTRIM(MONTH(GETDATE())), 2)+'_shield%'; if @count = 0 'then we need to execute the query using last month.  To accomplish this, change GETDATE() to DateAdd(-1, month, GETDATE())

Comment: An alternative, which is really doing the same thing, would be `code` if exists (current month query) begin run that same select end else begin run the select for the previous month, again by replacing GETDATE() with DateAdd(-1,month,GETDATE()) END

Comment: I cant thank you enough user1516044. You are my hero. Thank you so so very much for taking the time to answer all my questions. Thank you, sir.

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

```
WHERE process_ID like 'AB18-'+RIGHT('0' + RTRIM(MONTH(GETDATE())), 2)+'_shield%'
```

You can do similarly for the year as well

Comment: Thank you, Pete much appreciated.